# Puppeteer.js - Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a code problem that I could not fix for 2 days, here is my code:

```
const crawl = async () => {

try {

    const link = 'https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/wroclaw/?search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Ato%5D=3000&search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Afrom%5D=1000&search%5Bfilter_enum_rooms%5D%5B0%5D=two';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        'args': [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(link);

    // irrelevant stuff //
   

    for (let href of correctAdverts) {
        let hrefChecked = await checkForPromotedAdvert(href);
        console.log('entering ' + href);
        await page.goto(href, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            timeout: 0
        });

        pool.query('SELECT id FROM data WHERE href = $1', [hrefChecked], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack)
            } else if (res.rows[0]) {
                console.log("already in DB, " + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]))
            } else {
                insertData(page, href)
            }
        })

    }

    await browser.close();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
}
```

And this is my insertData function:

```
const insertData = async (page, href) => {
const olxPriceSelector = process.env.OLX_PRICE_SELECTOR;
const olxAdditionalPaymentsSelector = process.env.OLX_ADDITIONAL_PAYMENTS_SELECTOR;
const olxAreaSelector = process.env.OLX_PRICE_SELECTOR;
const olxDistrictSelector = process.env.OLX_DISTRICT_SELECTOR;

if (href.startsWith('https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/')) {

    let price = await getData(page, olxPriceSelector, null);
    let additionalPayments = await getData(page, olxAdditionalPaymentsSelector, 'Czynsz');
    let area = await getData(page, olxAreaSelector, 'Powierzchnia: ');
    let district = await getData(page, olxDistrictSelector, null, true);
    
    if (!district) {
        if (await page.$(olxDistrictSelector) !== null) {
            district = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, await page.$(olxDistrictSelector));
        } else district = 'undefined';

    }


    pool.query("INSERT INTO data (price,href,additional_payments,area,district) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) ON CONFLICT (href) DO NOTHING;", [price, href, additionalPayments, area, district], function () {})

}
}
```

And when I run it I get error : Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
Firstly I thought the `page.close` after the for of loop was the problem, but commenting it out doesn't seem to be fixing the problem

Can you see where might be the error?

Comment: This error can be due to a variety of reasons. Can you be more specific on what part of the code is throwing this error? You can add some log statements to see where it's coming from.

Comment: I can't really see which part throws that error, but I guess it's something within the InsertData function

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], so I think more work is needed to show the minimal failing, runnable code. Is the `pg` stuff relevant? I would remove it. That said, `await page.$(olxDistrictSelector) !== null` looks wrong--shouldn't that be `(await page.$(olxDistrictSelector)) !== null` (the `!== null` is pointless, you can just use the truthiness value of the `.$` promise). There are some definite code smells here (firing off callbacks outside the promise chain and not handling errors, passing the whole `page` around into many funcs, using `evaluate`/`$` when `$eval` would be much more straightforward).